How to solve current mirror with emitter degeneration
These circuits/discussion are from Art Of Electronics by Paul Horowitz & Winfield Hill, 3rd Edition, Figures 2.58 & 2.60.
Assumptions: \$Q_1\$ & \$Q_2\$ are matched, disregard base currents, \$V_{BE} = 0.6V\$
The first  circuit is easy enough to run through the calculations.

We know that \$V_C = V_B\$, and \$V_B\$ = \$V_{CC} - V_{BE}\$ therefore \$V_C = V_B = 14.4V\$. \$R_1\$ sinks \$\frac{14.4V}{14.4k\Omega}\$ therefore \$I_C \approx 1mA\$. The book continues that \$I_C\$ causes a \$V_{BE}\$ in \$Q_1\$ appropriate to the current at that specific temp, matching \$I_{C2}\$ to \$I_C\$.
But what happens when we add emitter degeneration? I can't figure out what \$I_E\$ is to calculate the vdrop across the resistor, and what the resulting \$V_E\$ is. Please help me work through this step by step. Thanks!


You have to put a backslash \ before the dollar sign $ for inline math.

You can solve this with the same approach you took for the first circuit. In the circuit without emitter degeneration, you did
$$I_P = \frac{V_{DD} - V_{BE}}{R_C}$$
Now, applying KVL on the input branch (i.e. the resistors and transistor on the left)
$$V_{DD} - I_P \cdot R_E - V_{BE} - I_P \cdot R_C = 0 $$
$$I_P = \frac{V_{DD} - V_{BE}}{R_E + R_C} $$
The same can be done for the output branch. Taking the derivative of the output current with respect to the load resistance shows how emitter degeneration desensitizes the output current to changes in the load resistance (i.e. it increases the output impedance of the current mirror).
You can see this intuitively without taking the derivative. If \$R_E \gg R_C\$, then \$R_E + R_C \approx R_E\$ and the output current doesn't change when \$R_C\$ changes. Here, \$R_C\$ refers to the resistance connected to the collector of the output branch, in other words, the load. Earlier equations that solve for \$I_P\$ refer to the collector resistor on the input branch.

In your degenerated diagram, the left side PNP is diode-connected. So to a first order, you can treat it as a diode in series with the two resistors of \$1\:\text{k}\Omega\$ and \$18\:\text{k}\Omega\$. Without doing the calculations, this should be approximately \$1\:\text{mA}\$. That current will be present throughout the series group, so \$1\:\text{k}\Omega\$ times \$1\:\text{mA}\$ gives about \$1\:\text{V}\$ across the emitter resistor. So the base will be about a diode drop lower, or around \$18.3\:\text{V}\$. This will be mirrored over to the right side PNP and so its collector current should be (if connected to a load that doesn't force saturation) about \$1\:\text{mA}\$, as well.
Assuming both BJTs are thermally coupled, the degeneration buys some immunity to part variations.
In the case of the current mirror without degeneration, variations in saturation current and emission coefficients lead to variations in base-emitter voltage vs collector current. And naked (no degeneration), there's a 10-fold increase in collector current for a \$60\:\text{mV}\$ variance in base-emitter voltage. Since two different parts might easily have \$30\:\text{mV}\$ variance between them, unmatched, this can mean a factor of 3 difference in collector currents (either way.) So that's terrible.
With the degeneration added, a \$30\:\text{mV}\$ variance means \$\approx 30\:\mu\text{A}\$ difference, which is much better in response to BJT variations alone (temperatures are assumed the same.)
A price is the voltage overhead.
More technically, though, you cannot assume a standard base-emitter (diode) drop for the left side PNP. It's actually going to behave according to the highly non-linear Shockley equation. So if you want a precise equation it takes some chain of mathematics to produce the LambertW equation that does make this calculation without iterating over and over. And you need to take into account base recombination currents, as well, while doing so. And BJTs also have an Early Effect that comes in with a 2nd order effect that especially applies to the right side PNP depending on its load. It's possible to account for all of this and develop a formula for both BJTs. And you can analyze that formula using sensitivity equations for whatever parameter you want, then. But this is usually reserved for people writing short "white papers."
A still more interesting question is how this all behaves if there is degeneration on only one side and not the other or where the degeneration resistor values are significantly different from each other. The answers are no longer quite so simple.

Assume for a moment that it works the same as without the 1.0 kΩ in series: the same current runs through your load as through your reference resistor.
If that is true, then the same currents run through the two series resistors.
If that is true, the voltages at the collectors of your two transistors are the same, and the schematic below just looks like the upper one, with a supply voltage reduced by 1.0 kΩ· I_c, but only in that working point.
So, since that obviously is a solution, the question becomes whether it's a solution that is stable – but here the simplistic transistor models start to fail; you will need to start taking nonlinear behaviour of h_FE and degradation into account. We can approximate, however, by trying to figure out what happens when we suddenly reduce the load resistance to a value smaller than the reference resistor.
For a moment, a higher current should flow through Q2. That in turn should increase degradation, reduce gain, of Q2, leading to lower current. Yep - this "swings back" by itself. Again, whether that is stable (in the temporal sense) will need a more in-depth analysis – but for "basically DC", this should work.
